# Add to cart and product options field in frontend issue - Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I have a issue on product view page. I add two radio buttons to hide product options and to show. But I have a problem when hide is selected and the custom fields are hide, when I press on Add to cart button I have this error "*Please specify the product required option(s).*" Is there any to add the product in cart with the fields empty? So the idea is to Disable Validation when hideRadio.click(function() { is selected

This is my javascript code to make the radio buttons to hide and show:

```
    var showRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(2)').find('input');
    var hideRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(1)').find('input');
        if(hideRadio){
             jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').hide();
             hideRadio.parents('dd').show();
                hideRadio.parents('dd').prevAll('dt:first').show();

        }

        hideRadio.click(function() {
          jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').hide();
          jQuery(this).parents('dd').show();
          jQuery(this).parents('dd').prevAll('dt:first').show();
        })
        showRadio.click(function() {
          jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').show();
        })
```

New Update:

Add this code into if(hideRadio){

```
         hideRadio.parents('dd').prevAll('dt:first').remove();
```

But still the same message "*Please specify the product required option(s).*". Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use classes to hide and show elements (toggle their visibility, as .hidden or something of your convenience) because, as stated in the Jquery docs, different elements can behave differently.

When you use hide() the element and its children become "invisible" to other jquery scripts. I solved such problem with css absolute negative position to hide my container (everything involving display:none, even in css class made my element "invisible")

Comment: no is not a problem, the hide and show function is work perfect, I can't pass validation, when I press add to cart if the fields are hide i have that message "Please specify the product required option(s)"

Comment: That is the point ! It is not the question if your hide/show functionality works - it will work, obviously ! It is that it makes your options container invisible and that's why options can't be found.

Comment: I think this is because is just leave it empty

Comment: This is another question. If options are required, set a default one. If you have a default one and it acts as if you hadn't any - it is because of the previously explained.

Comment: yes I want to leave all this like this, I don't want to remove required fields because I need them in the Show function, all I just want is to do something to add the product in cart with the fields hide

Comment: Required means "required" - cannot be empty

Comment: yes I know, but is not any method to remove that class when hide is selected? or something like this?

Comment: It depends on how cart scripts is set. Try to remove the options container itself or any element that indicates that it is set and required.

Comment: I see when a product is add to cart, in the input text field is add a class validation-passed maybe if I will add this class will work?